# How can I get a value only if it exist else return an empty dict in one line?

Tags: python

How to I check if a value exist and then return it and if it doesnt, return an empty dict {} (or any other operation) in one line?

I currently do the following which is will crash on none existing value + I also feel it could be written in a much more *python* way:

```
if (test[0].value):
   value = test[0].value
else
   value = {}
```

Comment: **exists** and **not empty** are **not** the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you have no guarantee that `test`, `.value`, or index 0 (`[0]`) exists:

```py
# Try and ask for forgiveness
try:
    value = test[0].value
except (NameError, IndexError, AttributeError):
    value = {}
```

#### If you know that `test[0].value` exists, but want to check if it is Falsey:

Use the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```py
value = test[0].value or {}
```

Or if some conditional logic is needed, you can use a ternary conditional/statement:

```
value = test[0].value if test[0].value else {}
```

Comment: if `test[0]` has no `value` defined (that's how I interpret "`test[0].value` doesn't exist"), your code would crash.

Comment: @KlasŠ. I disagree, if that was the case the code would crash in OP's example as well.

Comment: Indeed it would.  Can't see how it invalidates my point.

Comment: It's not what OP is asking for? OP added a segment of code which as they describe it, works for them. Hence this is the described behavior. Meaning OP probably means "if the value is falsey" as opposed to "has no `value` defined".

Comment: OPs code snippet doesn't do what OP said they want.  Either code is wrong (e.g., OP hasn't tested it for that particular use case), or description.  Addressing that inconsistency would improve your answer and help both OP and those who might find look for info on the subject.

Comment: Apologies for not asking properly! I meant if value is not defined, not if value is falsely - and yes, my code will crash, I will correct my question.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the clarification. I updated my answer to provide more information about each scenario, I hope it's written nicely and answers well :)

Answer (score 2):

From your question I assume that `test` is defined and is non-empty sequence, so that `test[0]` raises no errors (see other answers for those cases).

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with default:

```
value = getattr(test[0], 'value', {})
```

#### Demonstration

```
>>> import types
>>> a = types.SimpleNamespace() # so that we can add attributes
>>> getattr(a, 'value', {})
{}
# now let's add `value`
>>> a.value = 0
>>> getattr(a, 'value', {})
0
```

Comment: @KellyBundy, true, but I personally think that two lines is better that one-liner like `getattr(a, 'value') if hasattr(a, 'value')`, which is almost repeating the code.

Comment: @KellyBundy, check out updated version, for some reason I missed the most obvious solution on the first attempt :D

Comment: Would be `a.value if hasattr(a, 'value')`. But yeah, your new version is best (assuming it's the attribute that might be missing, not the `[0]`).

Comment: @KellyBundy, fair point about `a.value`!  As for `[0]` — I think that `test` being non-empty sequence is guaranteed.  I'll add that to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if:

- `test` exists in `locals()` or `globals()`
- the index exists: `-len(test) <= 0 < len(test)` under the condition `0` is an int.
- the class has the `value` property: `getattr(test[0], 'value', None)`

Then you use `test[0].value`.
Else you use `{}`

```
class NoData:
    pass
class Data:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value =value

value = test[0].value if ("test" in locals() or "test" in globals()) and -len(test) <= 0 < len(test) and getattr(test[0], 'value', None) else {}
print("NameError", value)
test = []
value = test[0].value if ("test" in locals() or "test" in globals()) and -len(test) <= 0 < len(test) and getattr(test[0], 'value', None) else {}
print("IndexError", value)
test = [NoData()]
value = test[0].value if ("test" in locals() or "test" in globals()) and -len(test) <= 0 < len(test) and getattr(test[0], 'value', None) else {}
print("AttributeError", value)
test = [Data({"a": 1})]
value = test[0].value if ("test" in locals() or "test" in globals()) and -len(test) <= 0 < len(test) and getattr(test[0], 'value', None) else {}
print("NoError", value)
```

Output:

```
NameError {}
IndexError {}
AttributeError {}
NoError {'a': 1}
```